# Confused regarding norm and why is $\langle a|b\rangle\langle b|a\rangle = ||\langle a|b\rangle||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-information

Given $\langle v|v\rangle=\sum_{i}a_{i}^2$ then $|||v\rangle||=\sqrt{\langle v|v\rangle}=\sqrt{\sum_{i}|a_{i}|^2}$.

Also, $\langle a|b\rangle=\langle b|a\rangle^{*}$.

So how then is $\langle a|b\rangle\langle b|a\rangle=||\langle a|b\rangle||^{2}=(\sqrt{\sum_{i}a_{i}^{*}b_{i}})^{2}$?

I think I have misunderstood what the norm is.

The only way I can see the above working is if $||\langle a|b\rangle||^{2}=(\sqrt{\sum_{i}a_{i}^{*}b_{i}})^{2}=\sqrt{\langle a|b\rangle\langle b|a\rangle}$

If this is the case, then I believe I have gotten confused regarding what the norm is actually doing, as I normally only come across it for either complex numbers or just single vectors. If the above does hold, then I take it to mean I need to take the sum of the product of the coefficients and their conjugate for vectors and complex numbers, but for inner products I must take the product of the innerproduct and it's transpose?

Comment: You understand that the norm is a function on vectors not *pairs of vectors* right?

Comment: It feels a little like you might be conflating norms and inner products with each other, not understanding they do different things.  You also might be conflating the modulus in $\mathbb C$ with the norm in $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: I think you are confusing the definition of a norm on your inner product space and the norm on $\mathbb{C}$ (by your question I'm assuming your vector space is over $\mathbb{C}$. Note that $z = \langle a | b \rangle$ is just a complex number and so  $\| \langle a | b \rangle \|^2 = \| z\|^2 =  z z^* =  \langle a | b \rangle  \langle b | a \rangle  $.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that to get the conjugate all I need do is swap the bras and kets. For some reason I convinced myself that doing was getting the conjugate transpose :/

Comment: @rschwieb what is the difference between the norm and the modulus? Generally I think I mix them up is due to notation.

Comment: @GaussStrife The modulus is a norm on $\mathbb C$, but it's not the same thing as the norm on $\mathbb C^n$. It does follow the same pattern since it's just the $1$-dimensional case.

Comment: @rschwieb I assume you mean that the modulus is the 2-norm, making it $a$ norm, but the norm in general is a function from the vector space to the real numbers >0?

Comment: @GaussStrife I don't know why I'd have to call it a 2-norm.  The complex inner product on $\mathbb C$ is associated with the ordinary modulus on $\mathbb C$.  That's all I meant by $1$ dimensional, that $\dim_\mathbb C \mathbb C=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the inner product
$$
\langle a | b \rangle = \sum_ia^*_ib_i
$$
we have
$$
\langle b | a \rangle = \langle a | b \rangle^* = \sum_ia_ib^*_i
$$
then
\begin{align}
|\langle a | b \rangle|^2 
 &=\langle b | a \rangle \langle a | b \rangle = \langle a | b \rangle^*\langle a | b \rangle = \\
 &= \sum_i a_i b^*_i \sum_j a^*_j b_j = \left( \sum_i a^*_i b_i \right)^* \sum_j a^*_j b_j = \left|\sum_j a^*_j b_j\right|^2
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, fixed that in the question

Comment: @GaussStrife also the inner product is wrong, it should be $\langle a|b\rangle=\sum_{i}a^*_{i}b_{i}$

Comment: yes I have made those syntax corrections

Comment: Yeah just got there myself. Always slips my mind that the bra is the conjugate transpose of the ket.